# Get type of union member

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to get a specific member of a union type based on a key in the union without explicitly defining each member of the union?

```
type Thing = {
  type: "person",
  data: {
    name: "John"
  }
} | {
  type: "building",
  data: {
    address: "111 Main Street"
  }
}

type Person = Thing["where 'type' = 'person'"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish narrowing down via [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.

Then we use the fact that the union of type `T` and `never` is the same as `T`

```
type NarrowUnion<T, N> = T extends { type: N } ? T : never;
type Person = NarrowUnion<Thing, 'person'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQUqiQBcUARJAE4DOA9kqQDR5QAmAhsGybvvkmwFsIJUgCkaceswC%20OaVAA%202ZoWFkARgFcEAGxbIUjZu07dm%20NixYUIVKiICMTqAFk2yKAGVgNiMFIycjg4qlAAcmwUFDQA7gCqSAh0ADwwDOEAfBiwUBAAHsAQSCxU2ATgamFQ8gD8OSRIEABuEBQA3CEVUAAKrbRI2RFRsQlJSKmIqOkA5JT90xk4QA)